# Apache FOP, custom fonts, kerning?

Tags: apache-fop, kerning

I've just used Apache FOP to produce a PDF/X photobook to be submitted to a photo print service. Everything seems fine, but kerning. With a custom serif font, e.g. the word "portfolio" isn't properly rendered (the problem lies with f-o, as o should be rendered under f's "head"). Installing the same font under Mac OS X, for instance, and trying TextEdit, the word is correctly rendered.

This is how I configured fonts:

```
            <font metrics-url="Muli/Muli-Light.xml"  
                  kerning="yes" 
                  embed-url="Muli/Muli-Light.ttf">
                <font-triplet name="Muli" style="normal" weight="300"/>
            </font>
```

where the XML file has been achieved by processing the TTF font as per FOP documentation. The file contains kerning pairs, that it's what should be needed AFAIK.

What am I missing? I'm using FOP 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is missing the word `file:/` like this:

```
<fonts>
  <font metrics-url="Arialuni.xml" kerning="yes" embed-url="file:/Library/Fonts/Arialuni.ttf">
    <font-triplet name="Arialuni" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
  </font>
</fonts>
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem so. In fact, embed-url seems to work without file:/, otherwise I couldn't see the font in the rendering. If it works for embed-url, I don't understand why metrics-url should be different. Consider that at the head of the file there's a couple elements to set the base paths:

 <fop version="1.0">

    <base>./</base>
    <font-base>./target/fonts</font-base>

In any case, I even try to hardwire file:/ and an absolute path, but nothing changes.

Comment: I have the same issue and still not able to figure out the solution